# Slack dialog doesn't close after form submission

Tags: node.js, express, slack

I created a slack dialog/form to collect some information from users; The form renders just fine and I can fill out the form without a problem but it doesn't close after I click Submit, instead it gives an error:

> We had some trouble connecting. Try again?

I've already sent back a 200 status OK as in the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#response).

```
// menu is the end point of my interactive messages
app.post('/menu', (req, res) => {
  console.log('from form submission:', req.body.payload)
  res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

What could be wrong? I can see the console log for my app, fyi.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sending a 200 OK is not enough.

It also has to be empty OR contain a list of input validation errors in the correct format as JSON. If your response contains any other text (e.g. a warning message) it will create this error.

As it says in the documentation:

> When the submission is without exception, your app must respond with
>   200 OK with an empty body. This will complete the dialog.

Comment: Excellent. This works. To be more clear. I used `res.send()` and it closed the dialog.

Comment: It is still quite unclear as to how to pose that. Could you elaborate on how you gt this to work?  I am currently using `res.send(200)` and then tried `res.sendStatus(200)`

Comment: @JustinRice As stated in above comment `res.send()` will do the trick

Comment: For those still getting this error, particularly with Flask apps - I found that setting the response mimetype to `''` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem (using golang and not JS). Responding with a 200 did not help, with or without body, but responding with a 204 code and no body fixed the problem.

Comment: this answer helps me, i'm using ruby and had similar issue.

Comment: What's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add if someone faces this problem in Python(Flask), returning empty body and 200 works. Here is how to do this:

```
return {}, 200
```

Full code (from my app)

```
def interaction_handler():
    try:
        logger.info('interaction')
        # Parse the request body into json
        data = json.loads(request.form["payload"])
        # logger.info(pretty_json(data))
        if (data['type'] == 'block_actions'):
            # Handle block_actions
            actions = data['actions']
            for action in actions:
                if action['action_id'] == 'settings':
                    # Handle settings action
                    Thread(target = handle_settings_action, args=[data]).start()
                    return 'OK'
        if (data['type'] == 'view_submission'):
            # Handle view_submission
            logger.info('view_submission')
            return {}, 200
        return 'OK'
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {'error': 'invalid request'}, 403
```

Interesting thing to note is that the need to return an empty body is only if the type is 'view_submission'; for 'block_actions', a non-empty body (here a text 'OK') also works!