# bot framework not receiving Slack dialog.open form response

Tags: botframework, slack

I am building bot with Bot Builder SDK for Node.js

The bot is for slack

I have configured the slack and botframework correctly, as per the doc [Connect a bot to Slack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-slack)

All communication between botframework, slack and node service is through HTTPS.
The framework is communicating with slack properly.

In Next step, I am working on slack [dialog.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open)

First of all, I could not find any method in Bot Builder SDK, to open the slack dialog, I even tried to [Implement channel-specific functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata)

Finally I was able to open dialog with direct post to: https://slack.com/api/dialog.open

But when I submit the form, I am getting error:

> We had some trouble connecting. Try again?

Please see the screenshot:
[image: slack dialog box with error]

The console displays the following error:

> Request URL: https://xxxxx.slack.com/api/dialog.submit
>
> Response: {"ok":false,"error":"curl_error"}

Slack send payload with "type":"dialog_submission".

I have tested that by changing the "Interactive Components -> Request URL", to my bot service.
To make slack communicate directly to my bot service.
Reference: section "Add and Configure Interactive Messages (optional)" in [Connect a bot to Slack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-slack)

So, I am sure message is being sent from the dialog box, when I click on submit button.

The message is lost between slack and my bot service. when Request URL is set to: https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions

I never receives any indication that service is receiving a message.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Following is the code that I used to open the dialog:

```
let RESTClient = require('node-rest-client').Client;
let FrameworkClient = new RESTClient();
let Promise = require('bluebird');
openDialogBox: function(token, trigger_id, callback_id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var dialog = {
          "title": "Issue Details",
          "submit_label": "Submit",
          "callback_id": callback_id,
          "elements": [
            {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Pickup Location",
                    "name": "loc_origin"
            },
            {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Dropoff Location",
                    "name": "loc_destination"
            }
          ]
        };
        var args = {};
        args.headers = {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token, 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'};
        args.data = {"trigger_id": trigger_id, "dialog": dialog};
        FrameworkClient.post("https://slack.com/api/dialog.open", args , function(data, response) {
          if (data && data.ok) {
            resolve(data);
          } else {
            reject();
          }
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the botframework, but I have implemented dialogs for my Slack apps. They work very differently from Interactive Messages. So if your framework does not officially support it, I doubt you can make it work. Example: any response back to Slack that is not an empty (excepts for an optional error property) will trigger this error. "We had some trouble connecting..."

Comment: A few follow up questions, are you using .net or node sdk? Can you please share your code you have that has gotten you to this point? Is any activity at all coming to your bot after submitting?

Comment: Thanks Erik for your response. I think the error it shows actually occurs, if the request URL, to which slack is posting response, does not respond back within 3 seconds.

Comment: Thanks JasonSowers for your response. I have added the code in original post that opened the dialog box for me. No activity is coming at all to my bot, after I submit the form.

Comment: I am using Bot Builder SDK for Node.js

Comment: @JatinderKumar Check also this answer about what the error means https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714834/slack-dialog-doesnt-close-after-form-submission

Comment: @ErikKalkoken thanks for this reference.

Comment: @JasonSowers, can you please check if Microsoft Bot Framework, responds to this kind of request as per requirement of slack dialog.open. The Bot Framework must be receiving payload with "type":"dialog_submission".

Comment: I need to look into this more, but in theory we should be able to accept that type.  It should come to the connector and be serialized in the ChannelData. This is why I was asking if the bot was receiving anything at all.  I'll be looking into this today, I'll let you know what I find out.

Comment: @JatinderKumar After talking through this with the team this is not something you would be able to accomplish via the bot framework we do not support this.  You would be able to do this by doing your send/receive outside of the bot and sending the resulting data to your bot.  Thank you for bringing this to our attention it is now on our radar and something we will look into supporting in the future.

Comment: @JasonSowers Any timeline when can we expect this to be supported? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per @JasonSowers (Engineer - Microsoft Bot Framework)

Microsoft Bot Framework do not support this right now.

They may support this in future.

Comment: Hi @jatinder-kumar, did you find an alternate way of doing this? I updated the Request url to an alternate api in my app but i am unable to get the API token manually from the new request url api post method, This can be got from ChannelData if we use Request Url as Azure Bot Service url but not when we use custom Request Url since azure stores it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I had added a button, on click of that opened the dialog. From the button click event you can get the token. from "session.message.sourceEvent"

Comment: Hi @jatinder-kumar, thanks for reply. Do you mean button click on slack message? i mean where is this object access code "session.message.sourceEvent" is written? It will be great if you can post the code. Are you still using MS bot framework? if so the user access token will be in Azure right?

Comment: Yes, it is slack action button. On click of that you get callback in the bot handle you have created for that button.

Comment: Thanks @jatinder-kumar, but i am not receiving it on my handle. Not sure what i am doing wrong. Payload i received is below.

Comment: {"type":"interactive_message","actions":[{"name":"xx","type":"button","value":"pho"}],"callback_id":"im_quote","channel":{"id":"Dxxx","name":"directmessage"},"user":{"id":"xxx","name":"xx"},"action_ts":"542","attachment_id":"1","token":"xxx","original_message":{"text":"quote?","username":"ChatBoto","bot_id":"xx","attachments":[{"callback_id":"im","text":"quote?","id":1,"actions":[{"id":"1","name":"tton","text":"ph","type":"button","value":"on"},{"id":"2","name":"ton","text":"Email","type":"button","value":"eon"}],"fallback":"how?"}],"type":"message"},"response_url":"c","trigger_id":"x"}

Comment: Just another thing, i have given the Slack Request Url as custom api in my bot project and not used Azure bot url(https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions) since Slack posts payload of both button click and dialog submit into the same url.