# Dialog box not closing

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to slack open.dialog method for some user input, the issue is once the user fill the field dialog box stays and throws error "We had some trouble connecting. Try again?"

I am using Django + restframework for command and dialog url.

I have tried sending empty body with 200 , but that did not work either.

```
return Response(data='',status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## adding code here so that

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

   slack_message = request.data

   payload = json.loads(slack_message.get('payload'))
   channel = payload["channel"]["id"]



    if payload['type'] == "dialog_submission":
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK) # responding to slack with 200
    # below is rest of the code which does not work.    
    if payload['token']==SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN:

        sc.api_call('chat.postMessage',
                    channel=channel,
                    text="we are working on your request , will update you shortly :)")

        summary = payload["submission"]["summary"]
        user_id = payload["user"]["id"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack dialog doesn't close after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714834/slack-dialog-doesnt-close-after-form-submission)

Comment: @ErikKalkoken not exactly a duplicate , yeah but similar , so issue i am facing is i can respond with 200 but the thing is how to proceed with rest of the code after return statement.

Comment: your app should terminate directly after to ensure the reply is actually sent. if you app keeps running after the return for more than 3 seconds and thus the response is actually sent later it will not work

Comment: @ErikKalkoken so now i am using thread to call a function to do processing on the data reciveved , but still this is not working.

Comment: i am using thread and returning the response in one function and doing rest of the processing in other however dialog box is still not closing any ideas why : Thread(target=self.process(payload,)).start()           
 return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return {"isBase64Encoded": True, "statusCode": 200, "headers": { }, "body": ""}
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending an HTTP 204, because that is a response with no content. It will work just fine.