# We had some trouble connecting error when submitting slack dialog (Slack API)

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I am building a slack app connected with a Symfony application that uses slash commands and dialogs as UI to create new users, accounts and projects and store them in a database.

I use a slash command to trigger a dialog with input fields and store the submitted data in a database, send a 'user successfully created' message to slack as well as a 200 response with an empty body, as described in the documentation.
However, when I fill in the input fields and press submit, I receive an error message with *'We had some trouble connecting. Try again?'*. This error also prevents the dialog from closing.

The submitted data is still received correctly by my application and stored to the database and the 'user successfully created'-message is also send correctly to slack. So the whole process seems to work correctly, the only problem is that the dialog doesn't close and shows the error message.

I also tried to immediately send a http 200 response, without processing the submitted data first and this gives the same error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack dialog doesn't close after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714834/slack-dialog-doesnt-close-after-form-submission)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already send the 200 response with an empty body. I also tried to send an response with a list of input validation error, but results in the same error.

Comment: Then please add the relevant part of your code to the question. I think its the only way people will be able to help you find the bug.

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @NebiMAydin: Try a 204 response and no body. This helped me solve the problem (using golang).

Comment: For those still getting this error, particularly with Flask apps - I found that setting the response mimetype to `''` resolved the issue.

Comment: In django DRF returning a response with `{}` body closed the dialog for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Golang, the only thing that worked was responding with status 200 and empty body:
`w.Write(nil)`.

I am not sure which lang are you using but try responding with an empty body.
Responding with 204 did not work for me.