# How to fix the 'Having Trouble Connecting' error from slack dialog to google sheets

Tags: json, python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack-api

I am trying to build a Slack slash command that can open a dialog and send the results to google sheets using google app script. I have gotten the dialog to open, but when I try to send it, I get the error -

`We had some trouble connecting. Try Again?`

I have spent hours on stack overflow trying to solve my issue. I think it has something to do with the returning 200 / blank message. The problem is that I don't know where to add that in my google script. My experience is in Python and I don't know enough javascript to know where to add the relevant return 200 piece. I have added the google javascript below this as I was unable to attach the file.

I have tried in several ways to add the relevant return, but I don't know where to add it or how to structure it. All the examples I have found don't appear to work with Google App Script (doesn't support arrow functions for example).

```
function doPost(e) {
var params = e.parameter;
var token = params.token;
var text = params.text;
var trigger_id = params.trigger_id;
var slackUrl = "https://slack.com/api/dialog.open";
if (token == ""){ 
  var dialog = {
    "token": "", 
    "trigger_id": trigger_id,
    "dialog": JSON.stringify({
      "callback_id": "ryde-46e2b0",
      "title": "Submit a Slack-Update",
      "submit_label": "Update",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Yesterday",
          "name": "yesterday",
          "placeholder": "What did you finish yesterday?"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Today",
          "name": "today",
          "placeholder": "What will you work on today?"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Blockers",
          "name": "blockers",
          "value": "None"
         }
      ]
    })
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : dialog,
  }; 
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackUrl, options);
} 
else{
  var res = {"text":"failed token verification!"} 
  return 
ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput();
}
```

I believe that I can format the responses correctly in google sheets once I receive the raw json, I just need to get past this step and actually receive my slack dialog response in google sheets.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly assumed the issue is that Slack expects an 200 OK response with an empty body from you.

Here is how to send that with Google Apps Script:

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput("");
```

I tested it with a Slack Dialog and it works.

This is similar to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714834/slack-dialog-doesnt-close-after-form-submission).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Does that mean I only need to add quotes to the last line of my code? Or do I need to add that return statement somewhere else? I added the quotes and I am still getting the trouble connecting error.

Comment: Yes, just adding the empty string should work. It did when I tested it.

Comment: Here is the code I used for testing. I basically only removed the else part. Maybe this helps. https://gist.github.com/ErikKalkoken/fff3c91c5daa3e8ffb13a4d97d4013db

Comment: Since you've been so helpful so far, do you know how to make this response appear in a google sheet? I tried
```
  if (typeof e !== 'undefined') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('SlackUps');
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  }
```
but I got an error of 
```
cannot call method getRange of null
```
even though I'm sure my sheet still has that name.

Comment: I am happy to help, but please make a new question since this looks like a new topic.

Comment: Also if this answer solved your question, please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the check-mark. Upvotes are also always very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I also made a sample Slack app with Google Apps Script which is using a spreadsheet as data storage. In case you are interested: https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slack-sample-app-gas