# Response format for a Slack modal submission using Bolt?

Tags: javascript, http, hosting, slack, bolt

I'm using Bolt for developing my slack bot, but I'm having trouble submitting the pop-up modal. My understanding is that this modal will send a POST payload to /slack/form URL (see photo below), so I've used Bolt's customRoutes handler to response with a 200 code and empty body (per [Slack's documentation](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals)). However, I continue to receive the following error in my hosting platform's logs (Render) when clicking 'Submit':

`[ERROR]   An unexpected error occurred during a request (POST) made to /slack/form`

I've experimented with variations of the response per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714834/slack-dialog-doesnt-close-after-form-submission), but none have seemed to work so far with my level of understanding. Has anyone had experience working with Bolt and Modal submissions to offer some guidance?

**Slack URL configuration for modals**

[image]

**Submit error**

[image]

**Code**

```
// This is my URL handler
    {
      path: "https://slack-glossary-bot.onrender.com/slack/form",
      method: ["POST"],
      handler: (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write();
        res.end();
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Correction, I've solved it - per Bolt's documentation (see image below), all request URLS (including interactivity payloads) must end in /slack/events.

[image]

[image]

Thus, I've changed my code to the following:

```
    {
      path: "https://slack-glossary-bot.onrender.com/slack/events",
      method: ["POST"],
      handler: (req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.write();
        res.end();
      },
    },
```